# I am prompted with "Page not found We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested" when attempting to edit my question

Tags: support, edits, 404-not-found

When I attempt to edit a question I asked on Stack Overflow, I am prompted a page stating:

> Page not found. We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

I am using Firefox 64.xx and JavaScript is enabled. I am able to post questions, but editing seems not possible within the same session.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So, it turns out you're not actually a human. According to the UserAgent string your browser is sending, you're really [The Googlebot](http://www.google.com/bot.html).

Stack Overflow is a site for *humans*; [we treat robots as second-class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322042/is-the-community-user-able-to-earn-badges/322050#322050), and as part of that we don't let them edit posts. Until you are able to demonstrate some humanity, you'll be unable to edit questions.

(I assume you're using this useragent as a way to get certain sites to show you pages without a lot of cruft, or maybe you have an extension or something installed that does it for you. Either way, if you disable your extensions - run Firefox in "safe mode" - you should be able to edit without problems unless the extension has *permanently* changed your useragent, in which case [you'll have to manually change it back](https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/))

Comment: Note that Firefox doesn't need extensions to change the user agent string; it's just an entry in the about:config called `general.useragent.override`. (This is also explained in Shog's last link, but in more words.)

Comment: Is that the reason [the bot wears the 'not a robot' badge?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot?userid=-1) :0